# How to define a variable as a function of another variable?

Tags: variable-definitions

I want to define a variable `q` which is a function of `t`. And I want to define another variable `qdot = dq/dt`.

Then what I want to archive is that if I have a function `f = a*Sin[q]`, and when I take the derivative `df = D[f,t]`, *Mathematica* returns:

> ```
> a*qdot*Cos[q].
> ```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Try using `Dt[]` instead of `D[]`

Comment: You mean like this: `f[t_] := a*Sin[q[t]]; D[f[t], t]` gives `a Cos[q[t]] q'[t]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FGpK3.png)

Comment: @belisarius The problem with Dt[] is that the constant in my function also got differentiated.

Comment: @Nasser I tried your suggestion and it gives me a good result. I can even define q'[t_]:=qdot[t], so D[f[t],t] gives Cos[q[t]]qdot[t]

Comment: @Nasser If this works for the OP, please consider posting an answer:)

Comment: @Nasser or cast a close vote if you wish :)

Comment: @Kuba oh, this was long time ago. I do not think the answer is worth posting as it nothing new. It is just a derivative. May be OP can close this question if they wish ;)

Comment: @Nasser I don't think OP is around. And I already voted here so I can't again :/

Comment: @belisarius Added a bit about the `Constant` attribute to your solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [total derivative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) `Dt` will give you an answer assuming every symbol has a derivative, unlike the partial derivative `D`. To protect your constant, you can give it the attribute `Constant`.

```
SetAttributes[a, Constant]
f = a Sin[q];
Dt[f, t]
(* a Cos[q] Dt[q, t] *)
```

Comment: Nice experiment

Comment: Yes, definitely a worthwhile effort. I shall endeavor to do the same, my good sir! (+1)