# How to define a variable to be a function of all the arguments but one?

Tags: functions, variable-definitions, differentials

I have several variables (coordinates)  $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, z$ and a lot (21, to be precise) functions $g_i$ which are assumed to depend on  $x_1, x_2,x_3, x_4$, but not on $z$. I also have a function `Differentiation` which uses `Dt` in its definition. I would like to apply `Differentiation` to my functions $g_i$.

I found that [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30804/how-to-define-a-variable-as-a-function-of-another-variable) proposed giving constants the attribute `"Constant"`. However, I cannot apply it directly, as my functions are constants only with respect to one variable.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: `Dt[x^2 y + z, x, y, Constants -> {z}]`?

Comment: or ``Internal`InheritedBlock[{Dt}, SetOptions[Dt, Constants -> {z}]; 
 Differentiation[x1,x2,x3,x4,z]]``?

Comment: Hello, @kglr ! I tried to implement your suggestion with a simple function `diff[expr_, x_] := Dt[expr, x];`. However, `Internal`InheritedBlock[{Dt}, SetOptions[Dt, Constants -> {z}]];diff[z r, z]` gives the same answer as `diff[r z , z]` -  `r + z Dt[r, z]`, when expected simply `r`. Did I somehow misinterpret your suggestion?

Comment: @klgr And as far as I understand, `Constant` attribute corresponds to setting all derivative of a variable to zero. And I want all the derivatives of other variables wrt this one to be set to zero.

Comment: @klgr I think that I've found solution: `ff[expr_, x_] = Dt[expr, x]; A /: Dt[A, z] = 0; ff[A B, z]` returns `A Dt[B, z]`. Thanks for help!

Comment: that's a very good solution. I suggest you self-answer the question.

Comment: An MWE possible?

Comment: @ΑλέξανδροςΖεγγ could you explain, what MWE is, please?

Comment: @NickTerziev a minimum working example

Answer (score 1):

With suggestions from @kglr I arrived at the following solution for a toy problem of differentiating $AB$ with respect to $z$, assuming that $A$ doesn't depend on $z$, using  `A /: Dt[A, z] = 0`, which sets the derivative of $A$ with respect to $z$ equal to zero:

```
ff[expr_, x_] = Dt[expr, x];
A /: Dt[A, z] = 0;
ff[A B, z]
```

returns `A Dt[B, z]`.